# Assign a specific Data from a JSON Response

Tags: json

I have a JSON response like below

```
[
{"A":2,"B":3,"CountVal":5,"Operator":"Addition"},
{"A":6,"B":8,"CountVal":84,"Operator":"Multiplication"}
]
```

I have to assign only **"CountVal" : 5** to a variable called **result**

I have tried lots of methods, but was not able to do.

Can anybody out there help me in finding a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access it like jsonArrayName[0].CountVal in javaScript. If it is in some other language you should use some jar/ classes to convert the thing to json and make use of the methods prescribed in them.

FYI: Accessing JSON Object in JavaScript
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Tutorial for Accessing JSON from different Languages. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var jsondata=$.getJson(resourceUrl);
 var data=JSON.parse(jsondata);
 var result=data[0]["CountVal"];
```

Comment: @SuperHomet I am getting an error as follows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". Any idea why so?

Comment: @Jomon, I think you should get data with $.getJson() function.